# Snakemake slowing down exponentially due to large amount of files being processed

Tags: performance, optimization, snakemake

I am currently writing a pipeline, which generates positive RNA sequences, shuffles them and afterwards analyses the positive sequences and the shuffled (negative) sequences. For example, I want to generate 100 positve sequences and shuffle EACH of those sequences 1000 times with three different algorithms. For this purpose, I utilize two wildcards (pos_index and pred_index) ranging from 0 to 100 and 0 to 1000, respectively. As a last step all files are analysed by yet another three different tools.

Now to my problem: The building process of the DAG takes literally hours, which is followed from an even slower execution of the actual pipeline. When it starts, it executes a batch of 32 jobs (because I allocated 32 cores for snakemake) and then takes 10 to 15 minutes to execute the next batch (due to some file checks, i guess). The complete execution of the pipeline would take approximately 2 months.

Below is a simplified example of my snakefile. Is there any way, I can optimise this in a way, so snakemake and its overhead is not the bottleneck anymore?

```
ITER_POS = 100
ITER_PRED = 1000

SAMPLE_INDEX = range(0, ITER_POS)
PRED_INDEX = range(0, ITER_PRED)

SHUFFLE_TOOLS = ["1", "2", "3"]
PRED_TOOLS = ["A", "B", "C"]

rule all:
    input:
        # Expand for negative sample analysis
        expand("predictions_{pred_tool}/neg_sample_{shuffle_tool}_{sample_index}_{pred_index}.txt",
            pred_tool = PRED_TOOLS,
            shuffle_tool = SHUFFLE_TOOLS,
            sample_index = SAMPLE_INDEX,
            pred_index = PRED_INDEX),

    # Expand for positive sample analysis
        expand("predictions_{pred_tool}/pos_sample_{sample_index}.txt",
            pred_tool = PRED_TOOLS,
            sample_index = SAMPLE_INDEX)


# GENERATION
rule generatePosSample:
    output: "samples/pos_sample_{sample_index}.clu"
    shell:  "sequence_generation.py > {output}"


# SHUFFLING
rule shufflePosSamples1:
    input:  "samples/pos_sample_{sample_index}.clu"
    output: "samples/neg_sample_1_{sample_index}_{pred_index}.clu"
    shell:  "sequence_shuffling.py {input} > {output}"

rule shufflePosSamples2:
    input:  "samples/pos_sample_{sample_index}.clu"
    output: "samples/neg_sample_2_{sample_index}_{pred_index}.clu"
    shell:  "sequence_shuffling.py {input} > {output}"

rule shufflePosSamples3:
    input:  "samples/pos_sample_{sample_index}.clu"
    output: "samples/neg_sample_3_{sample_index}_{pred_index}.clu"
    shell:  "sequence_shuffling.py {input} > {output}"


# ANALYSIS
rule analysePosSamplesA:
    input:  "samples/pos_sample_{sample_index}.clu"
    output: "predictions_A/pos_sample_{sample_index}.txt"
    shell:  "sequence_analysis_A.py {input} > {output}"

rule analysePosSamplesB:
    input:  "samples/pos_sample_{sample_index}.clu"
    output: "predictions_B/pos_sample_{sample_index}.txt"
    shell:  "sequence_analysis_B.py {input} > {output}"

rule analysePosSamplesC:
    input:  "samples/pos_sample_{sample_index}.clu"
    output: "predictions_C/pos_sample_{sample_index}.txt"
    shell:  "sequence_analysis_C.py {input} > {output}"

rule analyseNegSamplesA:
    input:  "samples/neg_sample_{shuffle_tool}_{sample_index}_{pred_index}.clu"
    output: "predictions_A/neg_sample_{shuffle_tool}_{sample_index}_{pred_index}.txt"
    shell:  "sequence_analysis_A.py {input} > {output}"

rule analyseNegSamplesB:
    input:  "samples/neg_sample_{shuffle_tool}_{sample_index}_{pred_index}.clu"
    output: "predictions_B/neg_sample_{shuffle_tool}_{sample_index}_{pred_index}.txt"
    shell:  "sequence_analysis_B.py {input} > {output}"

rule analyseNegSamplesC:
    input:  "samples/neg_sample_{shuffle_tool}_{sample_index}_{pred_index}.clu"
    output: "predictions_C/neg_sample_{shuffle_tool}_{sample_index}_{pred_index}.txt"
    shell:  "sequence_analysis_C.py {input} > {output}"
```

Comment: Maybe try [batches](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html#dealing-with-very-large-workflows) on the rule all?  I would be inclined to extract one of the wildcards (say SAMPLE_INDEX) and take that as a command-line argument.  Run the whole thing as a shell script so snakemake only works on a portion at a time.  It's effectively the same as batching, but may prevent the long, initial DAG calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I did not really have a large amount of files being processed, and also I did not experience a slowed down execution time, I did experience also a significant slow down of my **DAG computation step**.

Hence, I want to share my solution:

In cases where you refer in your input to an output of another rule, simply make usage of snakemake's in-build functionality of [rule dependencies and rule referencing](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#rule-dependencies):

```
### Bad example
rule bad_example_rule:
  input:
    "output_from_previous_rule.txt"
  output:
    "output.txt"
  shell:
    "touch {output[0]}"

### Solution
rule solution_example_rule:
  input:
    rules.previous_rule_name.output[0]
  output:
    "output.txt"
  shell:
    "touch {output[0]}"
```

I do not know why, but for me it speeded up the DAG build process by at least **x100**.